# Xib file renders when called by my page view controller but not as a tab

Tags: swift, interface-builder, xib

I'm rendering a Xib file which is a subview in a view controller, the view controller is called by setViewController in a pageviewcontroller . It works great. I then placed the same Xib sub view in a view controller called by my tab view controller and it doesn't render.

To try and get to the bottom of this weird occurrence I have removed all code such that there is no class attached to the UIviewcontroller parent of the subview Xib in both cases. It is now a pure IB implementation of the Xib and the Xib classes are identical.

So in my comparison between the two implementations the only difference is one is opened from a page view controller and the other from a tab. I even copied the working view controller just so I knew they were identical.

Has anyone had this experience (where the same Xib doesn't render in one workflow compared to another) or have an idea as to why the two implementations cause different results??

**Update**: I took it one step further. Now there is absolutely no code. The only thing that is in the Xib is an unattached label. It only renders when the parent view is called from a page view controller! Wtf

**Signin View Xib. (Works when instantiated from UIPageViewController:**

[image]

**SigninView.swift**

```
class SigninView: UIView, GIDSignInUIDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var view: UIView!
    var nibName: String = "SigninView"
    var delegate: SigninViewDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var googleButton: GIDSignInButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signoutButton: UIButton!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // properties
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Set anything that uses the view or visible bounds
        setup()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("AWAKING!")
    }

    @IBAction func tapSignOut(sender: AnyObject) {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        UserManager().logout()
        self.updateDisplay()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // properties
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Setup
        setup()
    }


    func setup() {
        view = loadViewFromNib()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        self.updateDisplay()

    }

    func updateDisplay() {
        self.googleButton.layer.hidden = false
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {

        //present vc on delegate
        let delegateVC = self.delegate as! UIViewController
        delegateVC.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {

        print("Dismiss view controller")

        let delegateVC = self.delegate as! UIViewController
        delegateVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.updateDisplay()

    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

        var success = false

        if (user != nil) {
            print("signed in? UID: \(user.userID), email: \(user.profile.email), name: \(user.profile.name), pic: \(user.profile.imageURLWithDimension(150))")


            UserManager().createUser(user)
            LocalDataStorage().saveContext()

            success = true

        } else {
            print("User not signed in.")
        }

        self.updateDisplay()

        if self.delegate != nil && self.delegate!.signInComplete != nil {
            self.delegate!.signInComplete!(success)
        }


    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        print("disconnected")
    }

}
```

**Working UIViewController that contains working Signin Subview**

[image]

**Working call from UIPageViewController**

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Intro", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IntroPage2")
setViewControllers([getSlide(index)],direction: .Forward,animated: true,completion: nil)
```

**UIViewController called from tab view that does not render signin subview**

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post some code so we can see which might be causing the problem.

Comment: @CleverError Code and views added. <*fingers crossed*>

Comment: This is probably some trivial mistake. Could you share the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting *AN* answer but really it's more of a work around. After hours of trying to finagle the views I get the code working consistently. To get it working created a *new* Xib and new *VC* file for the Signin module. I copied all the code from my original Signin class  to the new one and it worked. No code was altered.

So if anyone comes across the gnarly painful situation give that a shot! This could very well be an XCode bug.